# Rails validates unless

Tags: ruby-on-rails, validation

How can I have multiple `unless` statements? For example, in my model I have:

```
validates :email, unless: :guest?
```

But if try to have two unless methods:

```
validates :email, unless: (:guest? || :skip_validation)
```

It doesn't work. If `:guest?` is false but `:skip_validation` is true, the validation produces an error, requiring a valid email.

I got it to work by combining the `:guest?` and `:skip_validation` methods and passing that to validates, but was curious if unless: can take multiple methods?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So, you want to validate emails `if !:guest || !:skip_validation`, if the user is not a guest or we do not want to skip validation. Thus the unless condition is:

```
unless !(!:guest? || !:skip_validation)
```

Using De Morgan's laws, we can simplify this to:

```
unless :guest? && :skip_validation
```

So basically we have to use an `and` instead of an `or`.

Comment: Brilliant. I am still having some trouble wrapping my head around it. Wouldn't (:guest? || :skip_validation) return true if either is true, and therefore the unless statement would be true and the validation skipped? Any insight would be appreciated.

Comment: `unless x` is equivalent to `if !x`, basically, so `if !:guest && !:skip_validation` (your `unless` expression rewritten) would always require validation for guests, so that expression is incorrect. Trying to explain is also very confusing for me! Pages like [this one](https://signalvnoise.com/posts/2699-making-sense-with-rubys-unless) suggest doing as you did, make your own method that tests both conditions, which makes things easier when writing, and more importantly when you return a few months later and wonder what on earth you were trying to do!

Comment: Thanks! Much appreciated.